# Gather all packages in just one package in Eclipse (for Java project)

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, package

I have a very large Workspace, with many root packages, and I want all my packages to be under a unique folder... Is there any refactoring function to do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Right-click on the selected packages then choose move

Comment: Oh ! Sry, this was an easy one ^^'. Thanks !